# Avoid the undefined value in sub component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a sub-component for page:

```
<template>
  <div class="ll-page-wrapper">
    <div class="ll-page-div">
      <Page :total="data_count" :current="cur_page" @on-change="changePage"></Page>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      data_count: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I use it in parent component：

```
<ll-page :data_count="os_type_data.count" 
         @change_page_for_parent="os_type_change_page"></ll-page>
```

Sometimes the `os_type_data.count` is `undefined`, because it has not been fetched yet.

I want to avoid this issue, and I do not want to change code in the parent component, because it will affect the user's experience. I want to fix it in the sub-component, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `props` item has a validator param:

such as:

```
Vue.component('example', {
  props: {
    ...
    propF: {
      validator: function (value) {
        return value > 10
      }
    }
  }
})
```

you can change your sub component `props` code like bellow:

```
props: {
  data_count: {
    type: [Number, undefined],
    required: true,
    validator:function (value) {
      if (!value) {
        return 1
      }
    }
  }
},
```